# SSIS Script Task Debugging weirdness

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssis

I have a situation where there are two different users using the same machine, debugging the same package.  (SQL Server 2012)

When a breakpoint is set in a script task, for the one, when the breakpoint is hit, execution pauses appropriately, and VSS is opened, at the right point in the code, paused, ready to step through.

With the other user, visual studio opens, but the code is not in view.  Although the code can be opened, and the breakpoint is visible, the debugger does not appear to be attached and he can't step through.

To be clear, this is the same machine, same project, just two different users, and we're unable to identify any major differences between the two users (both are local admin).

The project settings are for interactive mode = true, 64 bit = false.

Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2010/03/17/why-the-breakpoints-that-i-set-in-my-script-task-not-script-component-in-the-data-flow-never-hits.aspx

Comment: Thanks @AnupAgrawal - that didn't fix this issue.  One of the users had broader admin permissions than the other, and elevating the permissions seemed to resolve the issue.  Not sure why that would be..

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this issue by not sharing the same source files amongst developers.  Each developer would have their own copy of the project, synchronized via source control e.g. TFS, VSS.  TFS in particular brings a host of other features and can be used online for free.

Comment: That's the intention, but meantime, the source isn't opened by the two at the same time, and since sharing copies via source would still have the same features (i.e. created by a different author), I'm not convinced this would resolve this particular issue?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: Thanks @Mike - as I mentioned it's definitely the intention.  Would be good to understand why that would make a difference, just for future reference.